# How to check the account created in Brain tree is set country US or not?

Tags: braintree

I have created **braintree sandbox test account**.I want to use **Braintree MarketPlace** feature, In Order to user that functionality account must created **US account**. How to check and change my account to Us, or i have to create new one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

You cannot change the country associated with a Braintree Sandbox. If you would like to test the Marketplace functionality within a Sandbox, though, you'll have to [sign up for a new Sandbox account](https://www.braintreepayments.com/sandbox), this time ensuring that you choose the United States for your country.

Comment: Thanks! for your response